# Testfor comparator not turning on

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a deathCount scoreboard called `Death` with a repeating always active command block with the command `/testfor @p[Death=1]` on singleplayer. Even when `Death=1`, the connected comparator doesn't turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the [target selector argument](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) for scoreboard values is `score_NAME=X` or `score_NAME_min=X`, where `NAME` is the name of the objective and `X` is an integer number. The former checks if the score is less than or equal to X, the latter is for greater than or equal to X. For a true equals, you need to put both.

In your case, you'll want to run

```
/testfor @p[score_Deaths_min=1]
```